# rollup+ts+vite packaging fails

Tags: typescript, vite, rollup

I want to use vite4+ts+rollup to develop ui components and upload them to npm. When I completed the development and passed the unit test, such a mistake occurred to him. Have you ever encountered this problem and could you please help me to explain the reason?
**[!] (plugin rpt2) Error: E:/project/personal_project/vue3/editor-component-ljq/src/components/LText/index.ts(3,19): semantic error TS2307: Cannot find module './LText.vue' or its corresponding type declarations.
**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/os2KK.png)

## error file

```
// E:/project/personal_project/vue3/editor-component-ljq/src/components/LText/index.ts(3,19)
import type { App } from "vue";
import LText from "./LText.vue";

LText.install = (app: App) => {
  app.component(LText.name, LText);
};

export default LText;
```

## main.ts

```
import type { App } from "vue";
import LText from "./components/LText/index";

const components = [LText];

const install = {
  version: "xxx",
  install: (app: App<any>) => {
    components.forEach((c) => {
      app.component(c.name, c);
    });
  },
};

export default install;
export { LText };
```

## package.json

```
{
  "name": "editor-component-ljq",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": false,
  "main": "src/main.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "run-p type-check build-only",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "test:unit": "vitest",
    "build-only": "vite build",
    "type-check": "vue-tsc --noEmit -p tsconfig.vitest.json --composite false"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.21",
    "vue": "^3.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-json": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/lodash-es": "^4.17.7",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^11.1.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^8.1.1",
    "@tsconfig/node18": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/jsdom": "^21.1.1",
    "@types/node": "^18.16.8",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.2.3",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx": "^3.0.1",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.3.2",
    "@vue/tsconfig": "^0.4.0",
    "jsdom": "^22.0.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "rollup": "^2.38.5",
    "rollup-plugin-css-only": "^3.1.0",
    "rollup-plugin-typescript2": "^0.29.0",
    "rollup-plugin-vue": "^6.0.0",
    "typescript": "~5.0.4",
    "vite": "^4.3.5",
    "vitest": "^0.31.0",
    "vue-tsc": "^1.6.4"
  }
}
```

## rollup.config.js

```
import vue from "rollup-plugin-vue";
import css from "rollup-plugin-css-only";
import typescript from "rollup-plugin-typescript2";
import { nodeResolve } from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import { name } from "./package.json";
const file = (type) => `dist/${name}.${type}.js`;

const overrides = {
  compilerOptions: {
    declaration: true,
  },
  exclude: ["src/main.ts", "node_modules", "src/App.vue"],
};
export { name, file };
export default {
  input: "src/main.ts",
  output: {
    name,
    file: file("esm"),
    format: "es",
  },
  plugins: [
    nodeResolve(),
    vue(),
    css({ output: "bundle.css" }),
    typescript({ tsconfigOverride: overrides }),
  ],
  // external: (id) => {
  //   return /^vue/.test(id)
  // }
  external: ["vue", "lodash-es"],
};
```

## tsconfig.json

```
{
  "files": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.node.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.vitest.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

## tsconfig.node,json

```
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node18/tsconfig.json",
  "include": ["vite.config.*", "vitest.config.*", "cypress.config.*", "playwright.config.*", "sfc.d.ts"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "types": ["node"]
  }
}
```

## tsconfig.vitest,json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
  "exclude": [],
  "include": ["sfc.d.ts"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "lib": [],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "types": ["node", "jsdom"]
  }
}
```

## tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.dom.json",
  "include": ["env.d.ts", "src/**/*", "src/**/*.vue", "sfc.d.ts"],
  "exclude": ["src/**/__tests__/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using esm, you probably need to include `.js` filename suffix.

e.g.

```js
// E:/project/personal_project/vue3/editor-component-ljq/src/components/LText/index.ts(3,19)
import type { App } from "vue";
import LText from "./LText.vue.js";

LText.install = (app: App) => {
  app.component(LText.name, LText);
};

export default LText;
```